# how to use Blade directives outside of Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I'm using Blade outside of Laravel using this  https://github.com/PhiloNL/Laravel-Blade  git and I can't figure out how to create custom directives.

Comment: Should just be `$blade->directive('name', function($expression) { // return something });` although I do wonder why you don't use something like Twig instead.

Comment: @ceejayoz blade has its advantages (like compiling to plaing PHP without having to add any class as a global like you have to with Twig), though of course Twig is more powerfull.